# Java main class

Tags: java

Here is my java code

```
public class Account {
    private String accName;
    private String accId;
    private int balance;

    Account()
    {
        System.out.println("This is an empty constructor.");
    }

    Account(String name)
    {
        accName = name;
        System.out.println("This is an valued constructor.");
    }


    public class main{

        public Static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Account a1 = new Account("raff");
        }
    }
}
```

cmd says ' "(identifier)" expected 
public Static void main(String[] args)'

I can't get the problem yet......

Comment: Do you really want Main class as inner class. Or did it accidentally?

Comment: not accidentally, willingly. it's just only practicing java.

Comment: But it's a mistake, now I understand...thanks for ur concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems there:

- public class within public class
- `main` shouldn't be a class there at all
- "Static", a mispelling of the `static` keyword

Probably this is how you meant to write that:

```
public class Account {
    private String accName;
    private String accId;
    private int balance;

    Account() {
        System.out.println("This is an empty constructor.");
    }

    Account(String name) {
        accName = name;
        System.out.println("This is an valued constructor.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account a1 = new Account("raff");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword, like all other Java keywords, should be written in lowercase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```